# Пару вопросов про JWT

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Доброго времени суток.
Делаю API на ASP.Net Core, использую авторизацию через JWT и появилось пару вопросов:

1. Нужно ли выдавать новый Refresh-Token каждый раз, при обновлении токена доступа? (В каком то из вопросов на enSO видел комментарий, что нужно, чтобы повысить безопасность, правда ли?)
2. Если выдавать новый Refresh-Token нужно, то нужно/можно ли удалять текущий (с которым пришел запрос) Refresh-Token из базы? (Токен живет 5 минут, если каждые 5 минут заполнять базу новыми Refresh-Tokena'ми (которые живут 7 дней), то это будет как-то слишком много данных, нет?)
3. Если выдают каждый раз новый Refresh-Token, то для чего делают их время существования большими? Например, 7 дней, для того, что если пользователь вошел и не заходил на сайт, например, 3 дня, то он смог обновить токен и продолжить работать без повторной авторизации?
4. Как сделать моментальный выход из системы для определенного пользователя? Например при обновлении пароля в ВК моментально выходит везде (телефоны, браузеры и пр.).

UPD-1: Ответ на первый вопрос найден:

> Рефреш токен (RT) — эти токены выполняют только одну специфичную
> задачу — получение нового токена доступа. И на этот раз без сервера
> авторизации не обойтись. Они долгоживущие, но одноразовые.

Comment: На все ваши вопросы я думаю без труда ответит [эта](https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc#file-tokens-md) статья.

Comment: Да, вполне информативная статья, но 4-ый вопрос остается открытым)

Comment: JWT - это по сути сессия, она хранится в базе. Просто удаляйте ее оттуда, да и все, при следующем запросе каких-либо данных ваш сервер будет просить клиента повторно ввести аутентификацию.

Comment: Хранить каждый токен в базе? При каждом запросе на сервер смотреть в базу? Звучит как-то не очень

Comment: Ну, для таких целей и делают токены доступа с малым сроком жизни, ибо контроля над ними как такового нету. Если он прям так нужен, то у вас варианта кроме как хранения этого токена в базе и проверки его действительности (черный или белый список) нету.

Comment: Хорошо, понял, спасибо
Если есть возможно, то подскажите как правильно передавать Refresh-Token в куках. Передавать HttpContext в сервис авторизации и просто записывать куку? MaxAge ставить исходя из срока действия Refresh-Token'a?

Comment: Это уже не ко мне, я JWT использовал лишь в простых C# клиентах и то там было нечто странное по типу `сервер<-->сервер`. В статье ведь написано как хранить и задавать куки с токенами, не подходит?

Comment: Нашел хороший пример, там показано как хранить, в общем, спасибо за ответы)